# Expression with Multiply Variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, reportbuilder

I'm building a financial report which reports based on debits & credits. I'd like to write an expression that will take the amount and multiply it by -1 if certain conditions are met. It would be something like this:

```
IF AccountClass = Revenue, Sum Amount *-1, IF AccountClass = Expenditure, Sum Amount *1
```

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder. The results of the report look like this:

| Account Class | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Revenue | 2,498.04 |
| Revenue | -10,500.03 |
| Expenditure | 500.00 |
| Expenditure | 700.00 |

I'd like it to show like this:

| Account Class | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Revenue | -2,498.04 |
| Revenue | 10,500.03 |
| Expenditure | 500.00 |
| Expenditure | 700.00 |

Thoughts?

In the dataset query I added an CASE THEN WHEN expression to setup AccountClass Revenue as Category 1 and AccountClass Expenditure as Category 2. I then created this expression for the calculation of the sum itself:

```
=Sum(VAL(IIF(Fields!Category.Value = "Category 1", Fields!Amount.Value,0)*-1))
```

BUT I can only get it to work for either Category 1 OR Category 2, I can't figure out how to make it work for both. Category 2 would be similary but *1.

Here is the full query:

```
SELECT
Custom1.Account
,Custom1.AccountClass
,Custom1.Description
,Custom1.[Year]
,@Quarter as [Quarter]
,Custom1.Budget
,CASE WHEN Custom1.AccountClass = 'Revenue' THEN 'Category 1'
WHEN Custom1.AccountClass = 'Expenditure' THEN 'Category 2'
ELSE 'Category 3'
END AS 'Category'
,SUM(Custom1.Amount) as Amount
,(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(t.[Amount for Balance]),0) FROM [Transactions] t WHERE t.[Account Number] = Custom1.Account AND t.[Fiscal Year] = @Year and t.[Period Number] <= @QuarterEnd) as YearToDate
,SUM(Custom2.Amount) as AmountLastYear
,(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(t.[Amount for Balance]),0) FROM [Transactions] t WHERE t.[Account Number] = Custom1.Account AND t.[Fiscal Year] = CONVERT(INTEGER,DATEPART(year, @Year)) - 1 and t.[Period Number] <= @QuarterEnd) as YearToDateLastYear
FROM [Account Details by Period] AS Custom1
LEFT JOIN [Account Details by Period] AS Custom2 ON Custom1.AccountID = Custom2.AccountID AND DATEPART(year, Custom2.FiscalYearEnd) = CONVERT(INTEGER,DATEPART(year, Custom1.FiscalYearEnd)) - 1  AND Custom1.Period = Custom2.Period
WHERE DATEPART(year, Custom1.FiscalYearEnd) = @Year 
AND Custom1.AccountClass IN (N'Revenue', N'Expenditure')
AND @Quarter = CASE WHEN Custom1.Period BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 'Q1'
WHEN Custom1.Period BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN 'Q2'
WHEN Custom1.Period BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN 'Q3'
WHEN Custom1.Period BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN 'Q4'
END
AND @Quarter = CASE WHEN Custom2.Period BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 'Q1'
WHEN Custom2.Period BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN 'Q2'
WHEN Custom2.Period BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN 'Q3'
WHEN Custom2.Period BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN 'Q4'
END
GROUP BY Custom1.Account
,Custom1.AccountClass
,Custom1.Description
,Custom1.[Year]
,Custom1.Budget
ORDER BY Custom1.Account
```

Comment: The specific solution depends on your DBMS (MySQL, TSQL, Oracle, etc), but you should be able to do this with a `CASE` statement in general.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: And please show your actual query.

Answer (score 0):

use `case` , you need to provide sample data but

if AccountClass condition applies to each amount:

```
select sum((case when AccountClass = 'Revenue' then -1 else 1 end) * amount)
from table 
...
```

if AccountClass condition applies to the whole sum() value  then

```
select sum(amount) * (case when AccountClass = 'Revenue' then -1 else 1 end)
from table 
...
```

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2012 and Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder. The results of the report look like this:

|Account Class |Amount
--------------------------
|Revenue  |2,498.04
|   |-10,406.86
|   |5,059.50
|Expenidture |7,275.00
|   |25,598.30
|   |13,730.50

Comment: @mehere I added it to your question , still its not clear ,  try to edit your question and explain it better,  but either ways , doesn't this answer your question  either way?